# python multiple inheritance: avoiding attribute naming conflict

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have two classes `Employee` and `Student`:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id  # the employee id

    ...methods omitted...   

class Student():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id  # the student id, different from employee id

    ...methods omitted...
```

Now I'd like to create a third class `StudentEmployee` which simply merges `Employee` and `Student`.

However, the goal is that both `id` are still kept in each inherited class.

Some thing like this:

```
class StudentEmployee(Employee, Student):
    def __init__(self, employee_id, student_id):
        Employee.__init__(self, employee_id)
        Student.__init__(self, student_id)  # overrides employee id
```

Note that both `Student` and `Employee` have the `id` attribute so in reality one will override the other.

**The question:**

How can I keep both `id` as they carry different meaning?

For example, is there some way to protect `id` from one class from being over-riden by another class.

### approach 1

One natural way is to change the class definition to:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.eid = id  # now "id" changes to "eid"

    ...attributes names in methods updated as well   

class Student():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.sid = id  # now "id" changes to "sid"

    ...attributes names in methods updated as well
```

However, I don't like this approach very much because `eid` is not as neat as `sid`.

Moreover, the above example might be too simplistic.

Let's imagine the two classes being "merged" have **many** shared attribute name, the code refactoring work won't be small.

Any other better ways?

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance or "private attributes" that start with double underscores. Makes it a bit harder to access in the subclass though.

Comment: For an instance of `StudentEmployee`, what should `se.id` return?

Comment: If composition doesn't work, perhaps a base class that both Employee and Student inherit from that contains their shared attributes?

Comment: To be clear: There is *not enough information* on how this new object would work. You need to [edit] your question and provide more information.

Comment: Composition solves me problem. Thanks